# Swift error when a method has not been called previously

Tags: swift

Hi I would like to ask if it is any way to get an error on xCode at compiling, when you are using a class method that needs to call first to another method?

I explain:

```
class MyClass {
  func initializeClass(){
  }
  func loadConfig() {

  }
}

var myClass = MyClass()
```

`myClass.loadConfig()` --> Throw Error while coding, the same as you get when you don't implement a required protocol function

Correct way :

```
myClass.initializeClass().loadConfig()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to approach this situation is by using the [Proxy Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). Rather than adding both methods to `MyClass`, make `loadConfig()` an instance method of `MyClassInitProxy`:

```
public class MyClass {
    public class MyClassInitProxy {
        let owner:MyClass 
        public func loadConfig() {
            // Do the config work using owner to access MyClass
        }
        private init(owner:MyClass) {
            self.owner = owner
        }
    }
    public func initializeClass() -> MyClassInitProxy {
        // Do preparation, then
        return MyClassInitProxy(owner:self)
    }
}
```

Now the only way one could call `loadConfig` is by obtaining `MyClassInitProxy` through `initializeClass()` call:

```
var myClass = MyClass()
myClass.initializeClass().loadConfig()
```

Comment: hehe, you can always just initialize MyClassInitProxy and call loadConfig on it. Also you can't have owner as constant on line 3 since you modify it later. This is not the correct usage of the Proxy design pattern :(

Comment: The use of `private` keyword prevents you from "always just initializing `MyClassInitProxy` and calling `loadConfig` on it". Also I perfectly can have owner as constant on line 3 since `init` is allowed (in fact, it is required) to assign all constant members.

Comment: "immutable value self.owner can only be initialized once" - get this error :D

Comment: @Lucho I compiled this with Xcode 7.2, no issues whatsoever.

Comment: My compiler says that I can call the following code anytime i like: `let nevergonnacallinitializeclass = MyClass();
MyClass.MyClassInitProxy(owner: nevergonnacallinitializeclass).loadConfig()
`

Comment: @Lucho This is because you are calling the private `init` from the same module.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - No, you can't have a compile-time error using this approach.

However if you want to make it impossible for anyone to instantiate your class without having configuration prepared, then just require the configuration as an argument in the initializer. E.g.

```
class MyClass {
    init(config: YourConfigType) {
        // do something with the config parameter
    }
}
... read config from somewhere and create config variable ...
let x = MyClass(config: config)
```

And then you have a "compile time error" whenever someone wants to use your class without having config setup initially.